# How to check whether a dataframe column value is not present in another column of same dataframe if nan value is present in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Can anyone help me out to check whether a dataframe column(Code) value is not present in another column(Place) of same dataframe in python

###### Below is the dataframe (df):

[image]

```
                Place     Code
0   Mumbai, MH34, IND     MH34
1                 NaN    KOL21
2     Pune, PU341, In    PU125
3       Chennai, CH54     CH54
4  Delhi, DL78, India      NaN
5     Hy, HYD7687, IN  HYD7687
```

I am trying to find the new dataframe if "Code" column value is not present in "Place" column if "Place" column value is non null with the below codes, but not getting the desired output.

```
df1 = df[~df["Code"].isin(df["Place"].values)]
```

###### Expected Output (df1):

```
            Place   Code
0  Pune, PU341, In  PU125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done in a quicker way, but this is an approach I'd take which answers your question. In short, it may be best to create a validation column that enables you to filter where your condition is equal to "False."

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# sample df
d = {'Place': ['Mumbai, MH34, IND', np.NaN, 'Pune, PU341, In','Chennai, CH54','Delhi, DL78, India','Hy, HYD7687, IN'],
     'Code': ['MH34', 'KOL21', 'PU125','CH54', np.NaN, 'HYD7687']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# convert to string to avoid float errors
df = df.replace(np.NaN,'')

# create a temporary column; also converting to list
df['Place_'] = df['Place'].str.split(',')

# loop each row to test if Code is in Place
lst = []
for row in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[row,1] in df.iloc[row,0]:
        lst.append(True)
    else:
        lst.append(False)

# create validation column
df['Test'] = lst

# delete temporary column
del df['Place_']

# filter to see items to check whether a 
# dataframe column(Code) value is not present in another column(Place)
df[(df['Place'] != '') & (df['Test'] == False)]
```

Desired Output:

```
     Place               Code   Test    
2    Pune, PU341, In     PU125  False
```